# How to use google API in Apps Scripts on Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I know my question sounds a bit mouthful, so just let me make my point clear: I need to do something like bringing data from Google Sheet to AWS (i.e. Athena), or vice versa.

However, because Google API is in need anyway, I surprisingly found that `require()` is not even a function in such kind of JS' twin-like language at all. Therefore, how can we use any third-party libraries on it?

Example ([github repo](https://github.com/googleworkspace/node-samples/blob/master/sheets/quickstart/index.js)):

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
```

Comment: What Google API do you want to use? And, from `I need to do something like bringing data from Google Sheet to AWS (i.e. Athena), or vice versa.`, in this case, I think that at Google Apps Script side, Sheets API might not be required to be used. I thought that you might be able to achieve this using [Google Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) and Class UrlFetchApp. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: What about fs? I need to read the credentials from a json file. So any alternative? And it seems that we have no way to upload any files like .json to the editor. It annoys me because I need to use my credentials.

Comment: BTW, essentially I am looking for `google.auth.OAuth2`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `What about fs? I need to read the credentials from a json file. So any alternative?`, you can retrieve data from a file on Google Drive. About `And it seems that we have no way to upload any files like .json to the editor.`, what is the editor? About `It annoys me because I need to use my credentials.`, I deeply apologize for this. About `BTW, essentially I am looking for google.auth.OAuth2.`, unfortunately, Google Apps Script has no `google.auth.OAuth2`. But I think that the workaround might be able to be thought. So, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gmail, Calendar, Drive, and most other Google Workspaces APIs in Apps Script by [enabling](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) Advanced Services.

- Open the Apps Script project.
- At the left, click Editor code.
- At the left, next to Services, click Add a service add.
- Select an advanced Google service and click Add.

Here's [an example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) on how to use the Drive API inside Apps Script.

Comment: But where can I find `google.auth.OAuth2`?

Comment: @MemphisMeng Why do you need google.auth.OAuth2? You don't need it to use Google Workspace APIs in Apps Script.